# can we partially update the state of a component in angular 6/ngrx

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx

I have a component named **FormComponent** and i have setup a reducer to managed the state of this component named **formReducer**.

On Initial load i get the data in following format

```
formInfo: {
   form1Data: {form1properties},
   form2Data: {form2Properties},
   form3Data: {form3Properties}
}
```

If i want to perform partial save on form1, How can i update my state.info.form1Data without affecting (resetting) form2Data & form3Data.

I want to perform a partial state update

my component HTML is in following format:

```
<div>
  <form> form1Data </form> /*api 1*/
  <form nestedForm> /*api 2*
      <form> form2Data </form>
      <form> form3Data </form>
  </form>
</div>
```

my Component Code inside ngOnInit:

```
this.actions.pipe(
  ofType(GET_FORM_INFO_SUCCESS),
  mergeMap(v => this.state)
).subscribe((data: any) => {
 if(data && data.formInfo) {
    //inits basic (form1Data) & nested form (form2Data & form3Data)
    this.initForm(data.formInfo);
 }
})
```

my reducer is in following format:

```
defaultState = {
  formInfo: {
    form1Data: {
      somePropertiesCollection: defaultValues
    },
    form2Data: {
      somePropertiesCollection: defaultValues
    },
    form3Data: {
      somePropertiesCollection: defaultValues
    }
  }
}

function formreducer(state: defaultState, action: ALL) {
    case GET_FORM_INFO_SUCCESS:
       return {state, ...action.payload}
    case FORM_SECTION_1_SAVE_SUCCESS:
       const form1Data = action.payload;
       const formInfo = {...state.formInfo, form1Data}
       return {...state, formInfo}
    case FORM_SECTION_2_SAVE_SUCCESS:
       const {form2Data, form3Data} = action.payload;
       const formInfo = {...state.formInfo, form2Data, form3Data}
       return {...state, formInfo}
}
```

I just started working on ngrx store and angular 6. I was able to do small stuff but facing problem in complex structure.

Comment: show us your formreducer defination and update action

Comment: @mayur how did you fix it ?

Comment: i am handling using view child. and me child component has serialize method. each component serialize method helps me handling at global level as well as individual level